# Xcode what files are referenced outside the project?

Tags: xcode, file, reference

I've an Xcode 4 project on my machine that for reasons of certs / profiles etc cannot be successfully built on my machine. So I've copied the project to another machine that has all the relevant certs etc and can build it for the app store.

Problem is there's apparently a few files that I've added with references instead of copying them into the project. So when I try to build on the other machine I get errors about missing files. I've no idea how many files there are and instead of giving me a list of all missing files it just errors on a per-file basis. So I find the missing file, remove or add it as needs be, copy project to other computer and try to build again. Another file is missing, rinse and repeat for who knows how long.

Is there any way of having XCode tell me which files are not directly part of the project? These are all image files I think, i can move the ones that need moving but doing it on this per file basis isn't really an option as it could take ages.

Comment: Found the answer, in BUILD PHASES you can see a list of the files under COPY BUNDLE RESOURCES and there it tells you where the files are located.

Answer (score 0):

To make Xcode collect those files you could create a new project, then drag the files from your first project to this new project. Don't have Xcode copy the files into this new temporary project. Then delete the files from your first project (just the reference to the files in the Xcode project, not the actual files). Then drag those files back into Xcode and have Xcode copy the files into the project directories. This is a little less work than manually looking up each files location.